# Relationship between expected absolute deviation and standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, robust, robust-standard-error

The standard deviation of a random variable $X$, $$\sigma = \sqrt{Var[{X}]} = \sqrt{E[X^2 - E[X]^2]}$$ is a very commonly used measure of "normal" distance from the mean of $X$. A much less frequently used measure is the expected deviation, which I'll denote $$d = E[|X-E[X]|]$$
I understand why we usually want to use $\sigma$. To give two reasons, it has nicer algebraic properties, and it gives more weight to larger deviations, which is often desirable. Further, I understand why in certain situations $d$ may be preferable.

My question pertains to the *relationship between the two*. More specifically, can we say anything about the conditions under which $\sigma = d$, $\sigma > d$, or $\sigma <d$? That is, what properties of a distribution would make one of those three statements true? What can we say about $|\sigma - d|$?

To open the question up a little bit further, are there any other interesting relationships between these two measures of spread?

Comment: A number of answers to questions already on site relate to the relationship between them. $\sigma$ is always at least as large as the mean deviation $d$; this follows (for example) from Jensen's inequality (though you can prove it from basic properties of means and variances) and is explicitly mentioned on the wikipedia page about $d$, the [Average absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation).

Comment: Specifically [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation#Mean_absolute_deviation_around_a_central_point)  relates to your $d$.  Note that $\sigma-d$ can be $0$ (when the variance is $0$), and it can be any larger value; you may find the ratio of the two more useful. At the normal distribution $\sigma/d$ is $\sqrt{\pi/2}\approx 1.25$ (again, see the wikipedia page) but since $d$ can easily be $0$ when $\sigma$ is positive,  it's more common to look at $d/\sigma$.